# Debugging an Issue which is in the StudentService class - Exception is not working in the code

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

This is the StudentController Class

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {
    private final StudentService studentService;
    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }
    @PostMapping
    public void registerNewStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        studentService.addNewStudent(student);
    }
    @DeleteMapping(path = "{studentId}")
    public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable ("studentId") Long studentId){
        studentService.deleteStudent(studentId);
    }
    @PutMapping(path = "{studentId}")
    public void updateStudent(
            @PathVariable("studentId") Long studentId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String email){
        studentService.updateStudent(studentId, name, email);
    }
}
```

Below is the StudentService Class:

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class StudentService {
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;
    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addNewStudent(Student student) {
        Optional<Student> studentOptional = studentRepository
                .findStudentByEmail(student.getEmail());
        if(studentOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken");
        }
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(Long studentId) {
        boolean exists = studentRepository.existsById(studentId);
        if(!exists){
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Student with ID " + studentId + " does not exists.");
        }
        studentRepository.deleteById(studentId);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateStudent( Long studentId,
                               String name,
                               String email){
        Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                        "Student with ID " + studentId + " does not exists"));

        if(name != null && name.length() > 0 &&
            !Objects.equals(student.getName(),name)){
            student.setName(name);
        }
        if(email != null && email.length() > 0 &&
                !Objects.equals(student.getEmail(),email)){
            Optional<Student> studentOptional = studentRepository.findStudentByEmail(email);
            if(studentOptional.isPresent()){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken");
            }
            student.setEmail(email);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the generated-request.http file

```
###
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/student/1?name=Maria&email=maria@gmail.com
Content-Type: application/json

<> 2023-04-14T205328.500.json
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= 9435561259
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

server.error.include-message=always
```

The Server is working as it should with all the working CRUDE properties, but in the PUT property of the server:

1. when i first try to update the name of the student with proper ID, it takes effect
2. When i check for the exception for an ID which is not there it works even then
3. But when i try to update the ID with the same email address it should throw an exception of "Email already taken".
   But somehow it is not doing that. Its still showing status code 200.

Can someone give their valuable inputs in this issue.
Your response are highly valuable to me.

Comment: you posted the controller instead of the service

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Sorry for the duplicate code, im new to this.
I have updated the service class with proper information.
feel free to ask if you need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return "Email already taken" when email already exists, here you have to change code like bellow :

```
  Optional<Student> studentOptional = studentRepository.findByEmail(email);
            if(studentOptional.isPresent()){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken");
            }
```

Hope this solve your problem.